# Excel export evaluate functions when opening

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a question about the opening of export excel sheets by excel. I have an application that exports to excel, which is build with OutSystems (PaaS development platform). When opening the excels the first time around any formulas like =1+1 are not evaluated, but shown only in text. When I double click these cells and press enter they do get evaluated.

I am using excel 2010 and 365 (tried on two computers). Automatic evaluation of formulas is turned on and when I type in =1+1 myself it gets evaluated immediately.

Is this so for all old versions of excel as well? And can I put something in a cell to make excel evaluate the formulas?

Comment: You can try to press `F9` when you opened your file. Perhaps then it re-calculates all formulas.

Comment: What format is the program exporting to? Is is plain text export into a `csv` which you are opening with Excel?

Comment: The end user is only shown with an actual .xlsx export. I do think though that internally the data is first made into .csv and then into .xlsx (although I am not a 100 percent sure and it is a propriatary platform)

Comment: If there are many formulas, you could try doing a find/replace Find `=`, replace with `=` (the same thing)  This might cause Excel to recognize the cells as formulas rather than text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is super late, but I figured I would comment since I ran into the same thing when trying to export similar data from a website I was developing. What I did is I dug into the underlying XML by changing the .xlsx extension to a .zip file ([per this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984254/how-to-view-the-xml-form-of-an-excel-file)). It was here that I could see that Excel typically constructs a cell with a formula like this:

```
<c r="J14" s="1"><f>H15*1.5</f><v>0</v></c>
```

The formula is in the `<f>` tag, `<v>` is the value. When you try to hard-code a formula into a cell from a 3rd party program, it forgoes the `<f>` tag completely. Therefore, Excel doesn't know how to properly interpret it.  I believe something similar happens with .xls files, but since they don't have the underlying XML structure I couldn't inspect the file.

I was able to fix my issue using SheetJS, however that is coded into the site. As for an offline fix, the cleanest solution I could find is to have a macro do the "replace = with =" trick, but even that is clunkier than I would have hoped and wouldn't actually work for me due to the systems we use. The true solution would be for the application that does the export to interpret the cell text beforehand, and construct cells in a `<f>formula</f><v>value</v>` format when the resulting text starts with an equals sign.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this does help with understanding the underlying problem.